# Command execution failed on project org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.publisher.feature

Tags: maven, wso2

Hi I got the below error while doing maven build for Carbon API management wso2 repo. I ran npm install already

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (npm install
>   (initialize)) on project org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.publisher.feature:
>   Command execution failed.: Cannot run program "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\npm" (in directory
>   "C:\projects\carbon-api\carbon-apimgt\features\apimgt\org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.publisher.feature\src\main\resources\publisher-new"):
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help
>   1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
>   build with the command [ERROR]   mvn  -rf
>   :org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.publisher.feature

Answer (score 0):

I ran node related commands separately and removed node commands from appropriate pom.xml. Now the build is success